# Figure Caption Alignment

Tags: pdf, caption

I have nearly 25 images in my PDF document. All of the images are centered. But I want just One image in left aligned. So I removed the \centering command that i used earlier. But my problem is, when doing so, figure becomes left aligned but the caption is still center aligned.

So, I need help 
to left align ONE of my Figure Caption.

Comment: You'll need to tell what document format (Word, PDF, etc.) you're talking about.

Comment: No it is not. "\centering" is not a PDF command. It sounds like you are using TeX (possibly without realizing it, although that's quite a stretch).